# Can charge pumps be combined?

Tags: charge-pump

I have an IC that requires a chargepump (L6470 dSPIN), and I need to build a circuit that requires 8 of them. Is is possible to combine the 8 charge pumps into one (1) unit to reduce the cost the circuit (part count an PCB routing)?

This IC seems to have internal circuitry that works with the flying capacitors to produce the required input voltage.

For more info see the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/analog/product/248592.jsp) on page 18.

Comment: We're going to need more info.  When you say "8", do you mean one Vin, eight Vout's or one Vin and one Vout that's a really high voltage?  What is Vin and Vout(s)?  What current do you need?

Comment: @DavidKessner - Check the datasheet; the motor driver he's using has an onboard chargepump for a MOSFET driver.  I'd assume that he's got 8 motor drivers and wants to avoid the redundant charge pumps.

Comment: @Kurt - Is the above assumption correct?  You have 8 of these ICs and want to avoid the extra charge pumps?  This is probably going to be a situation where you need to call an ST support engineer.

Comment: @Kevin, yes I want to avoid multiple chargepumps

Comment: @kurtnelle - Why do you want this?  You're driving 8 motors, so you probably have a decent sized PCB.  You only need an 0603 220 nF ceramic cap, an 0603 or 0402 10 nF cap, and a SOT323 dual series diode.  This is not a lot of PCB area, routing complexity (just step and repeat; your software may be capable of nesting a group of parts so it's really reduced to clicking 8 times), or cost (woahmygoodness!  These are [some expensive drivers!](http://www.findchips.com/avail/?part=L6470H)).  Yeah, these parts are going to cost about 1% of the cost of each driver IC.

Comment: @Kevin, I wanted to keep the PCB as small as possible, but if it's not practical to cut out the Charge pump stuff...

Answer (score 1):

If it were my project, I would lay out the 1st version of the board with individual charge pumps.  Then I would populate just one and connect the remaining controllers with a blue wire (as you're proposing).  Test worst case.  If it doesn't pass the test, you'll have 7 more charge pumps to come back to.

Judging from the datasheet and comments above, it should be possible to share output of one charge pump across several motor controllers.  If I were to do that, I would hook up Vboot pins together and fully populate one charge pump (of course).

Will the charge pump generate enough current for 8x motor controllers?  It depends on the frequency and the gate capacitance of the MOSFETs that controllers are driving.

On the other hand, this is not how ST (who designed the chip) intended for the charge pump to be used.  You would save 14 capacitors and 7 dual diodes.  You decide whether it's worth the engineering risk.

Comment: What are you looking at in the datasheet that says (1) the output of one charge pump is strong enough for multiple MOSFET drivers and (2) that the unused controllers can remain disconnected and not go into an error state?

Comment: @KevinVermeer   (1) Hopefully, you've read the 2nd paragraph of my post, where I comment on strength of current output.  (2) Which [potentially disconnected] pins do you mean when you say "unused controllers can remain disconnected" ?  Overall, chapter 6.3 and fig.4 are illuminating w.r.t. O.P.

Comment: I did read it, but "judging from the datasheet...it should be possible" seemed to iniicate you'd found something I'd missed. With respect to (2), I was referring to the CP pin and any sense circuitry on it and the VBOOT pin.

Comment: @KevinVermeer  (1) My approach to these sort of issues: if it could be feasible and it doesn't follow from the datasheet that it can’t be done [watch out for double negative], then it should be feasible. Make sure it's worth it.  Proceed with caution.  (2) CP is connected to a MOSFET half-bridge (fig.4).  It can in fact be left unconnected.  Is there sense circuitry?  I don't think there is.  The purpose of the charge pump is to provide higher voltage for driving gates of N-ch MOSFETs.  That doesn't require regulated supply, and I haven't seen a motor controller with a regulated charge pump.

Comment: Ah, we have a very different approach.  For my work, it must be stated that it can be done in the datasheet or in communication with the manufacturer, and then we test test independently at -40 to +125 C...we don't want parts coming back under warranty in 5 years because the CP could *almost* handle the load.  We're in agreement on the charge pump being "probably" suitable.

Comment: I agree that it should be possible. I also agree that I don't want stuff comming back on warrenty on "should be possible". I also don't want to induce higher cost in mass production if it could have easily been avoided (end user benifit).

Answer (score 0):

What Nick says

Proper datasheet [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00255075.pdf).

IF all Vs's are the same and
 if one charge pump has enough drive for all
 then it should work.

Do work through what will happen if eg one driver gets destroyed in some way - may this cause destruction of all driver ICs as they are now hard linked.

It seems you could feed in an external supply of your choice. Maybe from a more solid diode pump of from a small inductive smps.

Diode feed into all Vboot pins from a common supply may help security - diodes can be away from IC.s BUT decoupling at each IC may be a very good idea.

Is startup sequencing an issue. ie Vboot is caused by supply switching. Will the supplying IC be running properly when any given other IC needs it?

Comment: +1 I hadn't considered the security and decoupling aspects; +1 for good point. The datasheet just says that the Vboot should be higher than the input voltage, but I can't figure out how much higher. I was thinking to drive the circuit at 15 volts with 12 V Zenner between Vdd and Gnd